# Why does my Flask route listing function fail when I specify a converter for variable URLs?

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

I have a function I used to list the routes supported by my Flask application

```
# test.py
import urllib
import flask

def routes(verbose):
    """List routes supported by the application"""
    output = []

    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if rule.endpoint == 'static':
            continue
        options = {arg: "[{0}]".format(arg) for arg in rule.arguments}
        url = flask.url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)
        if verbose:
            line = "{:35s} {:25s} {}".format(urllib.unquote(url), rule.endpoint, ','.join(rule.methods))
        else:
            line = "{}".format(urllib.unquote(url))
        output.append(line)

    for line in sorted(output):
        print(line)
```

But if I have a function where I have specified the a converter for the [variable part](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules) of a URL, such as

```
@app.route('/plot/<int:xyrange>')
def plot(xyrange=10):
    ...
```

I get

> ```
> File "test.py", line 55, in routes
>     url = flask.url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 305, in url_for
>     force_external=external)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1648, in build
>     rv = self._partial_build(endpoint, values, method, append_unknown)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1570, in _partial_build
>     append_unknown)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1578, in _partial_build
>     rv = rule.build(values, append_unknown)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 718, in build
>     add(self._converters[data].to_url(values[data]))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 930, in to_url
>     value = self.num_convert(value)
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[xyrange]'
> ```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, the only thing you should do is to check the variable type to avoid this.

see:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[xyrange]'
```

you must have passed in a variable: `'[xyrange]'`.And it's a string.

You regulated the type of the url endpoint argument to `integer`, but you passed in other types. We all know that `int` methods can not change the string to integer.

So, check your argument's type before `redirect`, and if you can't confirm the type of the argument, don't use `@app.route('xxx/<int:xxxx>')`, buddy.

Comment: Use `@app.route('xxx/<xyrange>')` cause you can't control the type of the `xrange` . if you really need a integer, check `xyrange` type inside `plot` function , such as `if is instance(xyrange, integer):  #do something`

Comment: The given is that the rout *is* `@app.route('xxx/<int:xyrange>')`. That's the starting point: not having to change the application code to inspect it.